# Two methods for creating generic arrays with the same result, but only one works

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I recently tried to create an array of generics and found out it is not allowed: 
`Cannot create generic array of OptionSet<T>`

I decided to make a test class and found out that there is a different method with exactly the same result that does work:

```
public class Test {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        A<String> a = null;
        A<String> b = null;

        A<?>[] array1 = array(a, b); // fine, only a warning
        A<?>[] array2 = new A<String>[] {a, b}; // Error: Cannot create a generic array of Test.A<String>
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static final <T> A<T>[] array(A<T>... a) {
        return a; // fine, only a warning
    }

    private static final class A<T> {}

}
```

Why is that? Both methods have exactly the same result, but for some reason one throws an error and the other works fine, although it gives a warning.

Comment: This is due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Core point: generic types only exist at compiletime. They are replaced with their upper bound at runtime. To see how this kind of stuff is handled in the standard API, you can take a look at `ArrayList`'s implementation. It uses an `Object[] elementData`. When elements of type `E` are returned (e.g. by `ArrayList#get(int index)`), they are explicitly casted (and warnings are supressed through `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of casting is happening in case of method call via return type `private static final <T> A<T>[] array(A<T>... a)` which is not in case of `A<?>[] array2 = new A<String>[] {a, b};` where you're directly creating the instance.

to make it work You need to cast explicitly like below:

```
A<?>[] array2 = (A<String>[])(new A<?>[] { a, b });
```

What's happening is the elements are `A<String>` but not the array itself; it's still generic `A<?>` until you cast it explicitly.

Comment: Still, why do I need to explicitly cast it? I would expect it to be `A<String>[]` as long as I only pass `A<String>` elements to it while throwing an error when I don't.

Comment: Also, I noticed it doesn't work when I have a method `final <T> A<T>[] array(A<T> a, A<T> b)` because I cannot cast `A<?>[]` to `A<T>[]`. How do I solve that?

Comment: @Priv no this is not the reason here. You're returning single object instead of array of objects `A<T>[]`. Here you need to do similar thing i.e.either `return (A<T>[])(new A<?>[]{a,b})` or `return (A<T>[])(new A[]{a,b});`